# Publishing a nintex workflow while documents are still be processed by previous version of workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

If I have a document that is being processed by Workflow V1.1 then I publish Workflow V2.2..Will my document be completed by V1.1 or will it pick up and finish with V2.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your document will be completed by Version V1.1. The Workflow started with that version thus will close out with it, when the workflow begins a snapshot is basically taken of that workflow to process. New changes will kick in from a new event created or new task that kicks off that workflow.